# Plotting multiple data series that largely share the same y-axis values

Tags: excel, charts

I'm trying to create a chart, where I compare the costs of three Cloud resource allocation algorithms. The x-axis should show an SLO in milliseconds and the y-axis the cost of the algorithms' solutions. An algorithm should only be shown when it meets the SLO.

The problem is that the algorithms produce very similar or the same costs for certain ranges. How can I represent this nicely in a chart?

The images show some of the data and what I currently have as a line chart in Excel. Does anyone have an idea how I can do this better in Excel or some other program?

[image: Data]
[image: Line Chart]

Comment: This may be a better question for http://datascience.stackexchange.com since it's not programming related.

Comment: Great, thanks! Sorry for the late response. I was sick.